# I think i have a wrong pattern of AngularJS email or what?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUMlYfrvhTc&feature=youtu.be)

i put some spaces in front the @ mark but the submit button doesn't disappear, why? That is still a wrong mistake value and i want the submit button disapear.

my code is like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrljs">
    <form name='myForm' ng-controller='formctrl'>
        <input type='email' name='email' ng-model='email' required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/">
        <span ng-show='myForm.email.$error.email'> <font color='red'>invalid email</font></span>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' ng-hide="!myForm.$valid"></input>
    </form>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ctrljs', []);
        app.controller('formctrl', function($scope, $http){
          $scope.digits = {};
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

help me please, thank you.

Comment: Hmm... You should probably ***trim*** the value before checking if it's a valid email.

Comment: Or leave it as it is, let the user put spaces in front or at the end. I think it's a quite good UX. Than at server side trim the value and remove blanks from the beginning and from the end of string.

Comment: @Roko C, do you mean _ng-trim_? is there _ng-trim_ in angularjs?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: ok @RokoC.Buljan, i'll try

Comment: You can try but I don't think it'll do what you expect... Do as I've said. The email is valid in any case - even if the string isn't. Trim the value on server side before storing it or whatever you do with it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i had put **ng-trim="true"**, but doesn't work either, ok maybe i will use trim in php after submit. tq.

Comment: It's trimmed by default - unless you put `ng-trim="false"`. See the answer below. In any case - I'd use also a server side validation.

Comment: ok @RokoC.Buljan, i had tried in my programme and the result is there's no space in front of the string, your answer is correct, and the answer of DTing is correct also. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email is valid because angular will trim that whitespace for you. See the example below. If you type a space before example. You will see it become valid.

```js
var app = angular.module('ctrljs', []);
app.controller('formctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.email = "   example@example.com";
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ctrljs">
  <form name='myForm' ng-controller='formctrl'>
    <pre>{{email}}</pre>
    <input type='email' name='email' ng-model='email' required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/">
    <span ng-show='myForm.email.$error.email'> <font color='red'>invalid email</font></span>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' ng-hide="!myForm.$valid">
  </form>
</body>
```

Unfortunately there is no `ng-trim` for `type="email"` see the docs here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

If you want to prevent the auto trimming from happening you have to monkey patch.

---

Also from the doc, the `type=email` input already has a built in validation using the regex in this file:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js

You don't need to provide your own unless you need stricter or looser validation.

Comment: Thank you @DTing for your explain answer, i had tried in my programme and the result is there's no space in front of the string, your answer is correct. thanks again.

Comment: DTing, please help me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)